# Yii doesn't save editable grid after submit button

Tags: gridview, yii, grid, save, edit

unfortunately this solution doesn't **save** edited data on the grid, may i have some help?

- View name: admin
- Model name: Timesheet
- Controller name: TimesheetController

Thanks in advance.

**VIEW**

---

```
<form name="editableGridForm" method="post" action="editableGrid"> <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
                     array(
                     'id'=>'timesheet-grid',
                     'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
                     'columns'=>array(
                            array('name'=>'ID','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'25px')),
                            array('name'=>"DESCRIZIONE",
                                  'type'=>'raw',
                                  'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
                                  'value'=>'$data->getInputField(\'DESCRIZIONE\',$row)'
                                   ),
                            )
                       )
              );
              echo CHtml::submitButton('salva',array('class' => 'btn btn-success'));
              ?>
</form>
```

**MODEL**

---

```
public function getInputField($fieldName, $row, $options = array()) {
     return CActiveForm::textField($this, $fieldName, 
     array_merge(array("name" => "Timesheet[" . $row . "][" . $fieldName . "]"), $options)
     );
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

---

```
public function actionEditableGrid() {
    $model=new Timesheet('search');
    $notenData = $model->search();

    if (isset($_POST['Timesheet']) ) {
        foreach( $notenData->data as $i=>$item ) {
            if(isset($_POST['Timesheet'][$i])) {
               $item->attributes=$_POST['Timesheet'][$i];
                if ( $item->validate() ) {
                   $item->save();  
                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('admin'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a mass assignment to `$this->attributes`, Yii will only change the "safe" attributes. Attributes are safe when they have a validation rule or when they are simply being marked as safe (if no validation rule is suitable), as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('DESCRIZIONE', 'required'),
        array('DESCRIZIONE', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Either one of these rules is sufficient.

More info about doing mass assignments and the "safe" validator: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

I also noticed that you should replace `CActiveForm::textField` by `CHtml::activeTextField` in your model to prevent errors in php strict mode. `textField` is a non-static method of `CActiveForm`.

Edit: in order to debug why the saving is not working, replace this in your controller

```
if ( $item->validate() ) {
    $item->save();  
}
```

by

```
if ( !$item->save() ) {
    var_dump('Could not save, errors: ' . var_export($item->errors, TRUE) . ', attributes: ' . var_export($item->attributes, TRUE));
    return;
}
```

`save()` will call `validate()` automatically and return `false` if the validation fails.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan but it doesn't save yet. I've written required and safe rules on **Model** as you advice me, but still nothing...

Comment: I added some info to debug the validation. I assume that another field is causing the validation to fail. The ModelNameBehavior does not contain methods that could interfere with the validation/saving?

Comment: Hi Jonathan i've just commented these lines on the controller **search** action and now the grid let me save data: [CONTROLLER](http://pastebin.com/j9fVvVcN)

//$model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

//$model->RISORSA = Yii::app()->user->getState('profile')->cn;

thanks for your valuable support